# Fotorama 4 options : disable click on image

Tags: jquery, onclick, fotorama

Is there a way to remove click on the images?

As in fotorama3 with option "data-click=false" (Moving between images by clicking)

Some very practical options are no longer present in the settings fotorama4. Too bad ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s back in 4.2. Check this out: http://fotorama.io/customize/arrows-click-swipe/